# How can I force the z-scale of a ContourPlot to plot between (0, 1) if the data is < 1.

Tags: plotting, scaling

I'm plotting reflectivity, transmission and absorption data as a function of wavelength and angle on a ContourPlot. I want all the plots to be between 0 and 1 for comparison. However, some of the plot have data < 1 in all regions, and so the data will only plot between the lowest and the highest value.

I'm plotting the data using:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[{Absp}, {A0, 0.0, 90.0}, {lam, 300, 2000}], 
 PlotLabel -> "", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Angle (\[Degree])", "Wavelength (nm)"}, 
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.04], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 80}, {900, 2000}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, Contours -> 150, ContourLabels -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

As you can see, I've attempted to set the PLotRange for the z data to {0,1}, but the data persists in plotting between the lowest and highest values. (See attached image)

How can I force this to be plotted between 0 and 1?

[image]

Comment: 1. What is `Absp`? 2. Try `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, since you said that it's guaranteed your heights are within $[0,1]$.

Comment: Try to use Scale[]

Comment: [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) does not *scale* the respective variables in their corresponding ranges; it simply uses the specified ranges when displaying the plot; since using [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) doesn't seem to amount to much (or *I* couldn't make it work) perhaps you should consider [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html)-ing your data before plotting them

Comment: I have the same problem. Can somebody answer this question in more detail?